# External PHP Function from an AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery

All the strings on my site are pulled from a php language function named `lang()` inside **lang.php**. The function works when I use it within the **index.php** file, ie:

```
<p><? echo lang('hello-world'); ?></p>
```

However, if I use `elem.load('something.php');`, where **something.php** contains the same above code, nothing gets returned. In fact, if I type:

```
<p><? echo haslkdfhasdf('hello-world'); ?></p>
```

I don't even get an error. Now, after reading this [Call PHP function in ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884999/call-php-function-in-ajax-problem) and using header() I still don't get a returned string. My question then is, why doesn't the function work from inside an external php file loaded through AJAX, and what am I missing?

**[EDIT]**
Whoops forgot my AJAX code. Here's what I'm using to load the file:

```
$('#main-content').load('_foo/views/error.php');
```

Here is the error.php file:

```
<p id="ajax-error-message">
<? echo lang('html'); ?>
</p>
```

Now, I know that the file loads because if I replace the function with "echo 'Hello World';" it displays it properly. And here is the site incase you need it: http://afoobar.com , when you click on HTML5 Sandbox it executes the AJAX.

I'll try your suggestions in the mean time!

Comment: When you type `<p><? echo haslkdfhasdf('hello-world'); ?></p>` are you sure you aren't getting an error?  If the page is blank with no <p> tags, it means PHP error'd out and the display_errors setting was off so it just gives you a blank page (or at least dying after the first <p> tag.

Comment: Hmm, I have set all errors on using "error_reporting(-1);" and ini_set("display_errors", 1); in the first loaded .php

Comment: Ok so for kicks I added the error reporting to the top of error.php and now it displays the errors, which is giving me: Fatal error: Call to undefined function lang() in /Users/OMGCarlos/Sites/aFoobar.com/www/_foo/views/error.php on line 5. Does this mean it's not taking into consideration the files already loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I haven't seen your JavaScript code (minus the `elem.load()` I can't give you a guaranteed *solution*.  I can, however, suggest that you change `elem.load()` for something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'something.php',
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) {
        // do something
    },
    error: function(xhr, error) {
        try {
            console.debug(xhr); 
            console.debug(error);
        } catch (err) {
            alert(err);
        }
    }
});
```

Additionally, you could do practically the same thing using `$.ajaxSetup();`.

EDIT

Keep in mind that you have `include` (or `require`) all the needed files within your AJAX call because it is literally making a *separate HTTP request*.

```
// at the top of error.php
require_once '/path/to/lang.php';
```

Comment: I'll give this a try, I actually think it has to do with the server caching the file. I'll get back thanks!

Comment: Wow that was it, I needed to require the file. I didn't realize that it literally meant making a separate _fresh_ HTTP request. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. And now you have a slightly deeper understanding of how AJAX works.